# Can Fancybox be closed in its onStart or onComplete event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I would like to close the fancybox in its `onStart` or `onComplete` events. I tried `$.fancybox.close()` but it seems unable to close it.

Can Fancybox be closed in its `onStart` or `onComplete` events? How?

I am using Fancybox 1.3.4.

Thanks for any input!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.fancybox.close()` is the right method. What I don't understand is why you want to close fancybox within `onComplete` ... anyway, this works :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        "onComplete": function () {
            // close fancybox after 3 seconds
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.fancybox.close();
            }, 3000)
        }
    });
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L2UPg/)**

Works with `onStart` too  ... see updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L2UPg/1/)**

Comment: Hi JFK, again, thanks so much for the solution. It works, perfectly. I tested the 1 second, 2 second...9 second delay time, but none of them appears working. I know this number varies depending on machines. Why did you put $.fancybox.close() in setTimeout?  Regarding onComplete, I dont have to use it. I was just testing where I can close Fancybox, but indeed, I was unable to close it either in onStart or onComplete by straight use of .$fancybox.close().

Comment: @curious1 : I used `setTimeout` to avoid `$.fancybox.close()` being called before the handler could actually use it ... maybe that was the issue you had.